# Sum a multidimensional list in python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

How can i compute this :

```
[["toto", 3], ["titi", 10], ["toto", 2]]
```

to get this:

```
[["toto", 5], ["titi", 10]]
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, j in L:
...     d[i].append(j)
... 
>>> [[i, sum(j)] for i, j in d.items()]
[['titi', 10], ['toto', 5]]
```

---

Thanks @raymonad for the alternate, cleaner, solution:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> L = [["toto", 3], ["titi", 10], ["toto", 2]]
>>> for i, j in L:
...     d[i] += j
... 
>>> d.items()
[('titi', 10), ('toto', 5)]
```

Comment: Or simply `defaultdict(int)` with `d[i] += j` in the loop.

Comment: @raymonad Isn't python awesome?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group on the first item and then compute a sum:

```
In [1]: data = [["toto", 3], ["titi", 10], ["toto", 2]]

In [2]: from itertools import groupby

In [3]: from operator import itemgetter

In [4]: key = itemgetter(0)

In [5]: [[k, sum(l[1] for l in g)] 
    ..:    for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key=key)]
Out[5]: [['titi', 10], ['toto', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=[["toto", 3], ["titi", 10], ["toto", 2]]
d={}
for i in range(len(l1)):
    try:
        d[l1[i][0]]+=l1[i][1]
    except KeyError:
        d[l1[i][0]]=l1[i][1]
l2=[]
for k,v in d.items():
    l2.append([k,v])
```